# eigenvalue and eigenfunctions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the following eigenvalue problem

\begin{equation}
\beta xf'(x)+\alpha f'(x)+\alpha xf(x)=Ef(x)
\end{equation}

I would like to solve for $f(x)$ and $E$.

I know one set of solutions. $f(x)=e^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}x}$ and $E=-\frac{\alpha^{2}}{\beta}$. I was wondering if other solutions exist.